# Exploiting scraped data with python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I've made a script that allows me to scrap dynamic content from websites. For this script I've made a virtually infinite loop that scrape data and save them in a csv text file in order to be manipulated later on. While most of my calculations are not required to be live, still it would be very useful to me to make some quick live calculations. My problem is that I don't want to slow the script by making my calculations in the script and add them to the text file at the same time as the data. Why would be the best way to manage small live calculations without slowing my scraping script? 
Thank you!

Comment: Doing a quick calculation isn't going to slow the script down significantly. Just do your calculation and compare it on and off... my guess is that you won't even see a blip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start a new thread for each row you write to the csv file. My example uses youtube and scrapes a playlist, writes the links to the csv file as well as starting a thread where you can do something with each link.

```
import re
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep
import csv

def threaded_function(arg):
        print arg # do something with link
        sleep(1)

#Asks which playlist you want downloaded
print ('Which playlist do you want to download?')
playlist = raw_input()

#Access my youtube playlists page
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/user/randomuser/playlists?sort=dd&view=1&shelf_id=0")

#Access the 'Favorites' playlist
if playlist == 'Favorites':
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(text(), "Favorites")]').click()
    newurl = driver.current_url

    requrl = requests.get(newurl)
    requrlcont = requrl.content
    links = []
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requrlcont, "html.parser")
    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        #print("link " + str(link))
        if re.match("/watch\?v=", link.get('href')):
            links.append(link.get('href'))
        writer = csv.writer(open("output.csv", 'w'))
        writer.writerow([link])
        thread = Thread(target=threaded_function, args=(link, ))
        thread.start()
        thread.join()
        print "thread finished...exiting"

    print links
```

Test

```
python pyprog.py 
Which playlist do you want to download?
Favorites
...
```